# Running an external program (executable) with parameters in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am trying to automate a command line program.

The `exe` file takes one argument to run. For example:

`ztac.exe <mode>`
(where mode options are `safe`, `normal` or `debug`).

To run in debug mode I simply type this in the command line:

`C:\source>ztac debug`

How do I write a Python program to run this `ztac.exe` file while taking the different modes as inputs?

Answer (score 2):

```
program = 'ztac.exe'
arguments = ('safe', 'normal', 'debug')
argument = raw_input('Enter your argument: ')
if argument in arguments:
  subprocess.call([program, argument])
else:
  print('Illegal Argument')
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, however, I cannot run any other code while this is running. there a os.spawn type of implementation that can help me dos this?